# Lines-on-sides heading in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I'm trying to style my headings like so, with the dashes being solid lines and the text perfectly centered.

-------------------------------------Heading-------------------------------------

I've looked at several suggestions on here and other websites but I couldn't really get it to work. I want my text exactly in the centre with the lines length automatically adjusted depending on the length of the heading. This seems like a simple thing that should be a feature in Word.

Comment: Write the centered text with white background. Draw the line anchored to the text. Send it to back (after text).

Answer (score 1):

You can set tabs, with leaders.

Set one centered-tab in the middle of the line, and one right-tab at the end of the line, activate the leaders (type '----', not '...') for both tabs. Then write your text behind the first tab.